# Does warmer air of the same humidity condense faster?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, water, air, condensation

Warmer air can hold more moisture but can it also release it's moisture faster when touching a cold surface?
If air is warmed (for example by the hot side of a thermoelectric cooler ) before it moves over a cold condenser is the amount of water captured increased?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If air is warmed (for example by the hot side of a thermoelectric cooler ) before it moves over a cold condenser is the amount of water captured increased?

Assuming fully saturated air, yes, of course.  Warmer air can hold more moisture than cooler air.

As far as the speed of condensation goes, it will depend on the specific conditions.

If the cool surface is at the same temperature in both situations, the warmer air will be able to condense faster.  This will be because the heat transfer is greater.  To maintain the cool surface at the lower temperature when you have hotter air, you also need to cool down the surface quicker.

If the heat transfer rate is the same in both situations, the vapour should condense at the same rate in each situation.  This is because the warmer air will heat up the cool surface more; and thus reduce it's capacity to condense vapour.